# details on how to connect to geographically close datacenter

Tags: distributed-databases, dns

I am reading a book about distributed systems. One of the options of data replication mentioned is the use of a "multi leader" approach and place each leader in a *different datacenter*. The main point of different datacenters is to be geographically close to the user.

The author then discusses all the write conflicts that emerge by having multiple write leaders, but he doesn't say much on how to direct users to connect to geographically close data center.

For example, user in Austria makes a HTTP request to https://stackoverflow.com. Stackoverflow has datacenters in Germany and North America. DNS record point to the datacenter in US.

Is initial request always going to be pointing to the datacenter in US? I know that once a user is identified, I can instruct all AJAX and img requests to point to Germany (by changing the html response I sent back), but initial requests, such as page reload will always point to US.

This kinda defeats the purpose of being geographically close to users if they always have to connect to the distant server at first and only after that, the inline resources are fetched from a nearby server.. Am I missing some essential principles here?

Comment: That's not really a database administration question. Google for "load balancer".

Comment: yeah, it is in the gray area, but vital to implementation of distributed systems. Pointing users to load balancer experiences the same problem. The initial request can potentially always be sent from China to New York. Is this really it? Can't we do better?

Comment: initial request == html page request